# A die is thrown continuously

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

A die is thrown continuously. Find

1. the probability that number 6 will appear before the 10th throw
2. the probability that number 6 will appear for a third time on the 10th throw
3. expected value on the number of throws needed to observe number 6 for the first time

Here is my approach:

1.1) Consider as we have to fill $n$ places (cause we don't know how many times the die is thrown). Every places can be filled in $6$ ways.

We now have to count the no. of favourable cases, we have to place a six at any of the first $9$ places => $\binom91$ ways

Hence, Total no. of favourable cases is $\binom91 \times 5^{n-1}$.

So
$$P = \binom91 \times \frac{5^{n-1}}{6^n}$$

1.2) This time, we fix a $6$ at the $10$th throw, and we have to place $2$ six at any of the first $9$ places => $\binom92$ ways

Hence, total no. favourable cases is: $\binom92 \times 1 \times 5^{n-3}$

1.3) I have no idea about this. Please help me :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format math on this site.

Comment: For problem 1.1) you seem to have been looking only at the case where a six occurs **exactly once** within the first nine throws, but wouldn't you consider the cases where a six occurs multiple times within the first nine throws as also satisfying "the number 6 will appear before the tenth throw"?  You also use the number $n$ in place of nine or ten throughout your attempts.

Comment: As for 1.3) this is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and is well known and widely available in literature and resources.  I strongly suggest deriving the formula yourself, but if you wish to see someone else's work explaining the solution [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119872/on-average-how-many-times-must-i-roll-a-dice-until-i-get-a-6).

Comment: @saulspatz thank you for your comment, I'll check it out

Answer (score 3):

Your answer to number 1 is incorrect.  The probability that $6$ appears before the tenth rolls is the complement of the probability that none of the first $9$ rolls is a $6$. You seem to be thinking that the $6$ can appear exactly once.  The probability is $$1-\left(\frac56\right)^9$$

Your approach in the second case is correct.  You have to divide by $6^{10}$ to get the probability, though.

For the third one, this is the expectation of a geometrically-distributed random variable.  Let E be the expected number of throws until a $6$ appears.  Then $$E=1+\frac56E$$ because we always have to throw once and $\frac56$ of the time, a $6$ does not appear, and we are back where we started.  Thus, $E=6$.

Comment: which means for the first one, I'll have smt like: 1 - 5^9 x 6^(n-9)/ 6^n ?

Comment: @DotPoint I can't understand what that is supposed to mean.  You really need to learn MathJax.  I updated my answer to show the probability.