# Average number of rolls to roll a 6, using linearity of expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I read [On average, how many times must I roll a dice until I get a $6$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119872/on-average-how-many-times-must-i-roll-a-dice-until-i-get-a-6) but the answers all used geometric series, which I know how to do. I was wondering if there was a more "elegant" solution that uses linearity of expectation?

Comment: I find the question confusing. One solution: the expectation $x$ is the solution of the equation $x=1+\frac56x$. The other solution uses linearity of expectation and leads to a geometric series. If $X$ is the number of rolls then $X=\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ where $I_n=1$ if $X\ge n$ and $I_n=0$ otherwise, and $$E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(I_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1}.$$ Which one do you consider the "elegant" solution?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I haven't formally studied probability, so it is unclear to me whether the following *argument* is valid.  If you roll the die $(6000)$ times, you can expect to get $(1000)$ of those rolls to be a $(6)$.  Therefore, the average number of rolls per the occurrence of a $(6)$ is $\frac{6000}{1000} = 6.$

Comment: @user2661923 - If you flip a fair coin $1001$ times you expect a quarter of the $1000$ consecutive pairs to be HH.  But if you flip a coin until you get HH as a consecutive pair, the expected number of flips is $6$.  So your argument would need a little more justification

Comment: Re **my** previous comment, upon reflection, I think that the argument is **incomplete**.  The question of the average number of rolls per the occurrence of a $(6)$ is different from the average number of rolls per the *first occurrence* of a $(6)$.  The issue is therefore whether the argument can (somehow) be validly taken to completion.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I agree - re see my last comment; it just occurred to me.  Unclear if my *approach* can be **salvaged**.

Comment: @user2661923 possibly using the memorylessness property of the geometric distribution