# Combinatorics probability for high numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, problem-solving

I have a problem, which looks like a regular probability one, but has much greater numbers, then usually met. I have a **500'000 balls** in a bag, one ball is white and all others are black. We draw a ball, look at it and throw it back in the bag.

How many times should one draw a ball and throw it back until a white one is drawn with probability 95%?

The regular solution with degrees doesn't work here. The 499999/500000 is too small and the power is too high. How this can be addressed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "the regular solution" is and why it doesn't work?

Comment: something like that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119872/on-average-how-many-times-must-i-roll-a-dice-until-i-get-a-6

Comment: Just for additional context, what do you mean by "Combinatorics probability"?

Comment: Please post your efforts on a specific problem so that we can see what's not working for you.

Comment: You say 'the 499999/500000' is too small', and it is not small, it is bigger than the numbers that we usually meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Poisson approximation seems appropriate given the small probability of drawing a white ball.

Let $X$ be the total number of white balls in $n$ draws. We assume $X$ follows a Poisson distribution with mean
$$\lambda = n / 500,000$$
So
$$P(X > 0) = 1 - \exp(-\lambda) = 1 - \exp(-n / 500,000)$$
We want $P(X>0) > 0.95$, i.e.
$$1 - \exp(-n / 500,000) > 0.95 $$
so
$$\begin {align}
\exp(-n / 500,000) &< 0.05 \\
-n / 500,000 &< \ln(0.05) \\
n &> -500,000 \cdot \ln(.05) \approx 1.50 \times 10^6\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's think of this as a geometric distribution. Let X be the random variable 'number of trials until a white ball is pulled'. Then $X \sim Geo(\frac{1}{500000})$. We want to search for an $n$ such that $P(X\leq n) \geq 0.95$.

$
\Rightarrow 1-(1-p)^n\geq0.95
$

$
\Rightarrow (1-p)^n\leq 0.05
$

$
\Rightarrow n \geq \log_{(1-p)}(0.05) = \log_{\frac{4999999}{500000}}(0.05) \approx 1.498\times10^{6}
$

So you'd want to draw roughly 1.5 million balls to be 95% sure that you're going to have draw a white ball at some point.